# Check on Text in sqlite

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

You do a favorite job, but when you click the Add to Favorites button, you do not have just one click and the text is added with each click
You can examine the text within the database, but after checking, the value returns 0 at a time and the text is added

```
public int get_check_List_Favorite(String nameFav) {
  SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor rev = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM myFavoriate WHERE nameFav Like'"+ 
nameFav +"",null);
    int count = rev.getCount();
    return count;
}
```

---

code button

```
case R.id.btn_favorite_text:
            int check = db_sqlite.get_check_List_Favorite(nameFav);
            Log.i("note", String.valueOf(check));
            if (check > 0){
                Toast.makeText(general.this, "I've been added before", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else {
                db_sqlite.addFavoriate(wordClass.getmTextV1());
                Toast.makeText(general.this, "done added to favorites", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
            break;
```

Answer (score 0):

the get_check_List_Favorite method is a call you can pass the parameter to search item in the database ret method is

```
   public int get_check_List_Favorite(String nameFav) {
     SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
     Cursor rev = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM myFavoriate WHERE Colomname Like '%"+nameFav+"%'",null);
      int count = rev.getCount();
      return count;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change query

```
   // modify below method in SQLite helper class
   public String get_check_List_Favorite(String nameFav) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor rev = db.rawQuery("select * from myFavoriate where nameFav=?",new String[]{nameFav});
    if (rev.getCount() > 0 ) {
        rev.moveToFirst();
        return  rev.getString(rev.getColumnIndex("nameFav"));
    }
    return null;
}


   // call above method from activity that will return username
  case R.id.btn_favorite_text:
        String username = db_sqlite.get_check_List_Favorite(wordClass.getmTextV1()));
        if (username!=null){
             Log.i("note", username);
            Toast.makeText(general.this, "I've been added before", 
   .LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else {
            db_sqlite.addFavoriate(wordClass.getmTextV1());
            Toast.makeText(general.this, "done added to favorites", 
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
        break;
```

Comment: Nothing changed

Comment: Please can you share your SQLite helper class

Comment: you need file db sqlite for me?

Comment: i have check your code working fine, i have also edit above code please check now, first uninstall the existing app then install

Comment: Do not succeed the breakdown occurs in the add button

Comment: when removing this code "new String[]{nameFav});" it does not crash but sends 0 at a time

Comment: before getting value, make sure you have insert any entry in table

Comment: You changed the name of the database + you deleted the application and loaded it and did not succeed

Comment: if you are changing database name, then change  in every place where using in code and every time when you changes in db increase the database version

Comment: I changed everything and did not succeed

Comment: please share your latest code both SQLite helper and Activity class

Comment: I have sent you

Comment: check in email Spam messages

Comment: my email yousefabuaqel2001@gmail.com